# How to tween string characters on a div with TweenMax

Tags: javascript, string, gsap

How to tween string characters on a div with TweenMax in javascript like:

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TweenMax has a TextPlugin for that which makes it really simple:

```
TweenMax.to(element, 2, {text:"hello"});
```

That'll tween whatever text is in the element to "hello". You can even reverse() the tween or seek() to a specific time, etc. Docs are here: http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/plugins/TextPlugin.html

Just make sure you load the TextPlugin, otherwise it won't work.

Happy tweening!

Comment: and thanks for the really great library. I m also using it with three.js and it works just fine.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function TweenDivText(element, str) {
     var string = { counter: 0, val: str };
     TweenMax.to(string, string.val.length * 0.05, {
          counter: string.val.length, onUpdate: function () {
               element.text(string.val.substring(0, Math.ceil(string.counter)));
           },
           ease: Linear.easeNone
      });
 }
```

the element is a jquery element
you can change the writing time by changing 0.05.